# Unexpected freezeing with a Boostrap Modal

Tags: javascript, html, modal-dialog

I'm developing a simple frontend page written in native HTML, CSS using Boostrap framework.
I'm getting some problem related with opening of a modal, after it is opened I'm no longer able to interact with any element of the page.
Here's the interested piece of code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
    <title>3DFlix - Home</title>
    <link href="images/Materiale Sito web/IconaSito.png">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
          rel="stylesheet" 
          integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" 
          crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="header">
        <div class="header-navbar">
            <div class="header-navbar-start">
                <div class="header-navbar-logo">
                    <a href="index.html"><img width="228" height="58" class="logo" 
                        src="images/Materiale Sito web/HEADER_Tavola disegno 1.png"></a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="header-navbar-middle">
                <ul class="header-menu">
                    <li><a href="">Maker/Stampanti</a> <! Fare pagina Maker/Stampanti> </li>
                    <li><a href="">Blog</a> <! Fare pagina Blog> </li>
                    <li><a href="">Chi Siamo</a> <! Fare pagina Chi Siamo> </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            
            <div class="header-navbar-end">
                <div>
                    <button style="padding-right: 20px; background-color: transparent; 
                        border-color: transparent; color: black; font-size: 20px;" 
                        id="loginButton" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle"
                        data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false"> Accedi  
                    </button>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu">
                        <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" required><br><br>
                        <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" required><br><br>
                        <input type="submit" value="Login">
                    </div>

                    <button style="background-color: transparent; 
                        border-color: transparent; color: black; font-size: 20px;"
                        id="siginButton" class="btn btn-primary"
                        data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#siginModal"
                        aria-expanded="false"> Registrati 
                    </button>

                    <!-- Modal -->
                    <div class="modal fade" id="siginModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                        <div class="modal-dialog">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="modal-header">
                            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Registrati</h5>
                            <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-body">
                                <label for="fname">First name:</label>
                                <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname"><br><br>
                                <label for="lname">Last name:</label>
                                <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname"><br><br>
                                <input type="submit" value="Submit">                                
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Chiudi</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>        

                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    ....
    ....
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.10.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js" 
            integrity="sha384-7+zCNj/IqJ95wo16oMtfsKbZ9ccEh31eOz1HGyDuCQ6wgnyJNSYdrPa03rtR1zdB" 
            crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" 
            integrity="sha384-QJHtvGhmr9XOIpI6YVutG+2QOK9T+ZnN4kzFN1RtK3zEFEIsxhlmWl5/YESvpZ13" 
            crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>

    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: Website image]

When "Registrati" button is pressed I'm not able to do anything more, such as filling forms, closing modal or clicking on buttons, I can just reload the page.

UPDATE:
This is the style.css file:

```
body {font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif}

a {text-decoration: none; color: black;}

a:hover {color: black;}

.header {
    position: relative;
    box-sizing: inherit;
    z-index: 10;
    padding: 1rem 1rem;
}

.header-navbar {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
.header-navbar-start {
    padding-right: 1rem;
    margin-right: 0;
    flex: 1;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.header-navbar-logo {
    box-sizing: inherit;
    display: block;
}

.logo{
    display: block;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

.header-navbar-middle {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.header-menu {
   justify-content: center;
   display: flex;
   flex-wrap: wrap;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   list-style: none; 
   margin-block-start: 1rem;
   margin-block-end: 1rem;
   padding-inline-start: 40px;
   gap: 70px;
   font-size: 20px;
}

.header-navbar-end {
    padding-left: 1 rem;
    flex: 1;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.background {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0; left: 0; top: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%; height: 800px;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    display: flex;
}

.wrapper {
    justify-content: flex-start;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1200px;
    padding-left: 6vw;
    padding-right: 6vw;
    position: relative;
}

.wrapper-content {padding-top: 400px;}

.title {
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: normal;
    pointer-events: none;
}

.subtitle {
    font-size: 25px;
    font-weight: normal;
    pointer-events: none;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.wrapper-button {
    padding: 10px 15px 10px 15px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: none;
    position: relative;
    align-items: flex-start;
    font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    background-color: #eef138b6;
    border-radius: 20px;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    margin-left: 20px;
    box-sizing: content-box;
}

.home-page {
    background-color: #f4f4f4;
    display: block;
    margin-top: 9.8rem;
}

.section-one {
    background-color: white;
    width: 85%; height: 390px;
    margin: auto; display: block; position: relative;
    align-content: center;
    padding: 4rem;
}

.section-columns {
    margin-bottom: 2rem;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    display: flex;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    justify-content: center;
}

.section-one-content {
    flex-basis: 0;
    flex-grow: 1;
}

.section-two-content {
    flex-basis: 0;
    flex-grow: 1;
}

.section-three-content {
    flex-basis: 0;
    flex-grow: 1;
}

.section-one-img {
    margin: 0 0 1rem;
    margin-bottom: 2rem;
    box-sizing: inherit;
    display: block;
}

.section-two-img {
    margin: 0 0 1rem;
    margin-bottom: 2rem;
    box-sizing: inherit;
    display: block;
}

.section-three-img {
    margin: 0 0 1rem;
    margin-bottom: 2rem;
    box-sizing: inherit;
    display: block;
}

.one-img {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    display: table;
    align-content: center;
}

.two-img {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    display: table;
    align-content: center;
}

.three-img {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    display: table;
    align-content: center;
}

.section-h {
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-style: normal;
    text-align: center;
}

.stamp-list {
    padding-top: 2rem;
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    width: 85%;
    align-content: center;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.stamp-list-row {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: flex;
    flex: 0 1 auto;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.list-row-element {
    margin-bottom: 2rem;
}

.element-block {
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 5px 30px rgb(7 6 36 86 / 8%);
    background-color: white;
    transition: transform 0.25s;
}

.element-header {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    position: relative;
}

.element-img {
    border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    border-top-right-radius: 5px;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

.element-content {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    padding: 1.5rem;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}

.content-topbar {
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 5px 30px rgb(7 6 36 86 / 8%);
    background-color: white;
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    margin: -3.25rem 0 1.25rem;
    padding: 0.625rem 1rem;
}

.vendor-info {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.vendor-info-img {
    flex: 0 0 2.1875rem;
    margin-right: 0.75rem;
}

.vendor-img {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.vendor-name {
    font-size: 0.875rem;
    white-space: nowrap;
    margin: 0;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}

.content-middle {
    margin: 0;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}

.content-footer {
    padding: 1rem 1.5rem;
    border-top: 1px solid rgba(7, 36, 86, 0.075rem);
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}

.footer-attributes-primary {
    margin-right: 1rem;
    min-width: 0;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.attribute-provincia {
    font-size: 1.25rem;
    min-width: 0;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}

.footer-attributes-secondary {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.attribute-message {
    display: none;
    width: 380px;
}

.section-newsletter {
    background-color: rgb(204, 204, 204);
    width: 85%; height: 320px;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    align-content: center;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 2rem;
}

.newsletter-container {
    padding-top: 3rem;
    padding-bottom: 3rem;
    box-sizing: inherit;
    padding-left: 3rem;
    padding-right: 3rem;
}

.newsletter-columns {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    display: flex;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.newsletter-column1 {
    flex-basis: 0;
    flex-grow: 1;
}

.newsletter-column2 {
    flex-basis: 0;
    flex-grow: 1;
}

.column-h {
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
    margin-top: 0;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 30px;
}

.column-p {
    padding-top: 1rem;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: 400;
}

.newsletter-form {
    padding: 0.3rem 0.5rem;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: thin;
}

.checkmark-form {
    margin-right: 0.7rem;
    width: 15px; height: 15px;
}

.button-form {
    background-color: orange;
    border-radius: 20px;
    padding: 0.3rem 0.5rem;
    width: 7rem;
    border-style: groove;
}

.footer {
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    padding: 1.5rem 0;
    box-sizing: inherit;
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    padding-right: 2rem;
    padding-left: 2rem;
    width: 100%;
}

.footer-navbar {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    gap: 70px;
    width: 100%;
}

.footer-navbar-logo {
    box-sizing: inherit;
    display: block;
}

.footer-menu {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    gap: 50px;
}

.social-icons {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    gap: 30px;
}
```

Comment: what is the content of your js code:     <script src="script.js"></script>

Comment: script.js file is just empty actually, I updated the style.css file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aight now we know that it's a css problem.
First you should try to make your css file clearer... It's not easy to read a 500 lines css file so try to organize it by creating many css files that matches with a html component.
Exemple: a css file named header.css for your header, a css file named modal.css to custumize your modal, a css file named hero.css to custumize your hero section etc.

Second you should try to understand what is bootstrap doing by inspecting elements. You'll see that Bootstrap creates a div element with "modal-backdrop" class to create a "background" to your modal. The problem is you made something that changed the z-index and hide your modal.
So you can try to organize your css code and try to find the specific css line or just add this line to your css that will specify a correct z-index.

```css
.modal-backdrop {
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your code is working well here. I think you should show us these files content: "script.js" and "style.css"

Comment: the file script.js is actually an empty file; so i'm just updating the first post with style.css